# How do you return a string found with re.search in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, return, telnet

So this is my code:

```
class telnet(object):
    """conexiune"""
    def __init__(self):

        HOST = "route-views.routeviews.org"
        user = "rviews"
        password = ""

        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

        tn.read_until("login: ", 5)
        tn.write(user + "\r\n")

        tn.read_until("Password: ", 5)
        tn.write(password + "\r\n")

        print tn.read_until(">", 10)
        tn.write("show ip route 192.0.2.1"+"\r\n")

        self.y = tn.read_until("free", 10)
        print self.y
        tn.write("exit"+ "\r\n")

        tn.close()

    def re(self):
        self.m = re.search(r' Known via "bgp \d{0,5}"', self.y)
        if self.m:
            print self.m.group(0)
        else:
            print False
```

What I need to do is return self.m instead of printing it.  If I write 'return "This answer is: "+self.m', I get this error:

return "The answer is: " + self.m.group(0)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and '_sre.SRE_Match' objects

If I use print it prints it, but I don't know how to do it with a return statement.

This is what it has to return:

Known via "bgp 6447"

from this telnet output:
route-views>
show ip route 192.0.2.1

Routing entry for 192.0.2.1/32

Known via "bgp 6447", distance 20, metric 0

Tag 19214, type external

Last update from 208.74.64.40 4w1d ago

Routing Descriptor Blocks:

- 208.74.64.40, from 208.74.64.40, 4w1d ago

  Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1

  AS Hops 1

  Route tag 19214

  MPLS label: none

route-views>

I know that return is used for functions - that's why I added the '+'.  Btw I'm a Python beginner.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the actual error traceback (the entire  thing) along with the exact code that you used to generate that traceback?  You've got a bunch of different variants in your post ... `print self.m.group(0)`, `return 'the answer is:' + self.m` , `return "The answer is: " + self.m.group(0)`  etc.

Comment: this is the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JohnyB™\Desktop\junk.py", line 95, in <module>
    x.re()
  File "C:\Users\JohnyB™\Desktop\junk.py", line 43, in re
    return "The answer is: " + self.m.group(0)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and '_sre.SRE_Match' objects        this error appears if i put return "The answer is: "+self.m.group(0) instead of print self.m.group(0)

Answer (score 2):

I think in your 'return' statement you just missed out the '.group(0)'.

Try :

```
if self.m:
   return self.m.group(0)
```

Comment: when i do that it's not showing anything, just the telnet output.

Comment: Ok. As @Shpionus said in his answer, you should return the group(1). Actually group(0) means the whole string in which re has found the pattern, group(1) is the part matching the pattern.

Comment: Yes. If you will update regexp to specify what exactly you want to select from self.y you need use group(1).

Answer (score 1):

From documentation

```
>>> m = re.match(r"(\w+) (\w+)", "Isaac Newton, physicist")
>>> m.group(0)       # The entire match
'Isaac Newton'
>>> m.group(1)       # The first parenthesized subgroup.
'Isaac'
>>> m.group(2)       # The second parenthesized subgroup.
'Newton'
>>> m.group(1, 2)    # Multiple arguments give us a tuple.
('Isaac', 'Newton')
```

So, try this

```
>>> import re
>>> y = ' Known via "bgp 54574"'
>>> m = re.search(r' Known via "bgp (\d{0,5})"', y)
>>> print m.group(1) if m else False
54574
>>> y = ' Known via "bg p 54574"'
>>> m = re.search(r' Known via "bgp (\d{0,5})"', y)
>>> print m.group(1) if m else False
False
>>>
```

Comment: can you please add it in the code? i didn't get exactly what you ment.

Comment: I updated answer. Please, note, that I also changed regexp to select numbers from source string.